# Wondering how to do this?

Tags: python

I am trying to code a caesar’s cipher
I have this piece of code:

```
letters = ‘abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz’
```

`
and when I try and add a position this happens

```
position = letters.index(character)
```

NameError: name ‘character’ is not defined

I expected for it to give me the index of each letter

Comment: What exactly do you want to find the index of?  Like the error says, `character` isn't defined.

Comment: You haven't created a variable called `character`. Perhaps you were thinking of a for loop, as an example `for character in "this is my message":`?

Comment: I am trying to find the index of each letter of ‘letters’ so I can add a specific ‘key’ amount to it and use it as the ciphered text

Comment: You meant to put an actualy character for ```character``` right? For example:  ```letters.index('c')``` returns 2

Comment: I did mean to do that, I will edit my question with my code

EDIT: too many pending edits, so I will send you where I got this information from:
How can I know the position of a letter in the alphabet?
Start with this string of letters in the beginning of your program:
 
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
 
This is essentially the alphabet. For any given character, as long as it belongs to these letters, you can get its numerical position in the alphabet using this code:
 
position = letters.index(character)

Comment: You could try the *enumerate*   like this - ```for idx, char in enumerate(letters): print(char,  idx)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

for i in letters:
    print(i, letters.index(i))
```

This will yield an output:

```
a 0
b 1
c 2
d 3
e 4
f 5
g 6
h 7
i 8
j 9
k 10
l 11
m 12
n 13
o 14
p 15
q 16
r 17
s 18
t 19
u 20
v 21
w 22
x 23
y 24
z 25
```

Comment: I perhaps could have used ```character``` instead of ```i```.

Comment: I recommend using a dict for such thing: `letters_index = {char: letters.index(char) for char in letters}`, then you can do `letters_index["m"]` and it will return `12`.